# Ceasar Cipher in C w/ getch() and putch()

Tags: c

1.Im using C GCC Compiler, and im getting two warnings , (the code compiles though)
The Program Should Ask the USER for a the value of chiper , then it will tell the user to Enter 4 digits , and it will chiper them (The digits the user entered will not be displayed on the screen , the letters he entered will be chipered and displayed while hes typing (the chipered letter will take the place of the original letter).when I run the program, and I put the value of 2 as the chiper value . and then enter any 4 letters it displayes me this :

(what I entered : abcd)

it should display :
Enter (4 Digit Word)cdef
Press any key to continue . . .

It displays instead:
Enter (4 Digit Word)bcde
Press any key to continue . . .

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <conio.h>//added because a comment
 int distanceFunction(int distance);
 void encryptFunction(int distance , char digit1 , char digit2 ,char digit3 , char digit4);
 int main(void)
   {
       char digit1;
       char digit2;
       char digit3;
       char digit4;
       int distance;
       printf("Enter Distance");
       encryptFunction(distance , digit1, digit2 , digit3 , digit4);
       system("PAUSE");
       return 0;

   }
   int distanceFunction(int distance)
   {
       scanf("%d" , &distance);
       return distance;
   }
   void encryptFunction(int distance , char digit1, char digit2 , char digit3 , char digit4)
   {
       distanceFunction(distance);
       printf("Enter (4 Digit Word)");

       getch("%c" , &digit1);
       digit1=(((int)digit1)+distance);
       putch("%c" , digit1);

       getch("%c" , &digit2);
       digit2=(((int)digit2)+distance);
       putch("%c" , digit2);

       getch("%c" , &digit3);
       digit3=(((int)digit3)+distance);
       putch("%c" , digit3);

       getch("%c" , &digit4);
       digit4=(((int)digit4)+distance);
       putch("%c" , digit4);
   }
```

Comment: [Wikipedia About Ceaser Cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher)

Comment: `distanceFunction(distance);` pass to uninitialize variable and drop return value.

Comment: `getch("%c" , &digit1);` maybe  you want `scanf(" %c" , &digit1);` then `printf("%c" , digit1);`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY scanf will show the original letter , the assignment im given is to make it not show and display the chipered one.

Comment: As already pointed out, you have discarded the value entered as `distance`.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY what do you mean??

Comment: try `distance=distanceFunction(1024);`

Comment: Try it instead of what?? @BLUEPIXY

Comment: `distanceFunction(distance);`

Comment: Thanks @BLUEPIXY now I only need to rederect the letters when the output stream is over the number of the english alphabet

Comment: Im new to StackOverflow , do I need to close this thread

Comment: Use `%` operator.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY , Thats what I did. , its all good now

Comment: If that is the case there is nothing to say.

Answer (score 0):

`distanceFunction(distance);` pass to uninitialize variable and drop return value.
try `distance=distanceFunction(1024);` [instead of] `distanceFunction(distance);` – BLUEPIXY